# Computing the Petersson norm of newforms of weight 2 from the symmetric square $L$-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $f \in S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ be a newform with trivial character. I want to compute the Petersson norm $\lVert f\rVert^2$ of $f$, *not* normalized by $1/[\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}):\Gamma_0(N)]$, as in Gross–Zagier.

From [Numerical evaluation of the Petersson product of elliptic modular forms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115100/numerical-evaluation-of-the-petersson-product-of-elliptic-modular-forms), I came across the formula $$\lVert f\rVert^2 = \frac{(k-1)!}{2^{2k - 1}\pi^{k + 1}}L(\operatorname{Sym}^2(f),2)$$ with $k = 2$. I implemented this in Magma. If $N$ is not square-free, I guess the correct Euler factor for the symmetric square at $p^2 \mid N$ by testing if the functional equation for the symmetric square is satisfied with $1 \pm x$ or $1 \pm px$.

However, comparing with the result of PARI/gp (which *is* normalized by $1/[\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}):\Gamma_0(N)]$, so removing that normalization), it seems that I have to multiply my result by $N$ if $N$ is square-free, the reason for which I don't understand (maybe it's a convention of the implementation of the symmetric square $L$-function in Magma?). It is even worse for $N$ not square-free, e.g. $f \in S_2(\Gamma_0(125))^+$ or $S_2(\Gamma_0(147))^{w_3,w_{49}}$, where the normalization factors seem to be $125$ and $147 \cdot 7/8$, respectively.

PARI's code is hard to read, and Petersson scalar products are not implemented for $N \neq 1$ in Sage.

Can someone please shed light on this?

Comment: Indeed the PARI code is hard to read since based on a rather sophisticated algorithm which I developed, and as far as I know no other public system has the Petersson product for general $N$. I do not know if magma's implementation is public, but if you find that pari's normalization is incorrect please inform me so we can correct it.

Comment: You can compute conductor and the Euler factor at primes $p | N$ of the symmetric square $L$-function using the local Langlands correspondence. Cogdell and Michel work out exactly what this is for squarefree level (and all symmetric powers) in their 2004 IMRN paper. Martin and Watkins have a paper working out symmetric powers of elliptic curves $L$-functions. I don't know anyone has worked out the general case explicitly.

Comment: One dodgy step here is finding the "correct" Euler factor for the Sym^2 L-function. The point is that there are two different functions (differing only in the Euler factors at the bad primes): the imprimitive L-function L^{imp}(Sym^2 f, s) which is given by a tolerably straightforward formula in terms of the q-expansion coefficients of f, but doesn't have a functional equation in general; and the primitive one, which has a nice functional equation but is a pain to compute. Perhaps surprisingly it is the *imprimitive* one which is most straightforwardly related to the Petersson norm.

Comment: (cont'd) So if you are computing the special value of the primitive L-function using Magma, and then plugging this into the formula you quote, then you will get the wrong answers whenever primitive and imprimitive L-functions disagree.

Comment: Also, with the proper normalization of the $L$-function (meaning that $s$ is coupled with $1-s$ in the functional equation, not $k-s$ or some other nonsense), the special value to be considered is at $s=1$, not $s=2$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse I think the paper of Martin and Watkins only states the answers, and a paper of those two with Dummigan actually gives the derivation method. As you say, it doesn't seem to generalize easily beyond elliptic curves (their method includes a case-by-case analysis of the possible non-abelian inertia groups for $p=2,3$ (this suffices for elliptic curves), which I'd think is hairy in general).

Comment: @user334725, as I mentioned in my answer, you can work out the conductor and the Euler factors at primes dividing the level of the adjoint $L$-function or symmetric square $L$-function by work of Gelbart and Jacquet.

Comment: Indeed, I think I'm being overcomplicated in my generality. For the symmetric square (but not higher symmetric powers necessarily), the case of non-abelian inertia should just lead to a trivial Euler factor (maybe assuming trivial Nebentypus, which seems to be the case here). So the situation simplifies.

Comment: Magma's documentation http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1592#18361 seems to say it computes the bad Euler factors for elliptic curves using Dummigan-Martin-Watkins, but not in general. So you have to provide them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the formula you are trying to use is only valid for $N=1$, and thus needs correction in general.

Maybe Shimura's paper can help sort this out. https://doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160290618

In (2.1), which Shimura writes for $\Gamma_1(N)$ but that doesn't matter when the character is trivial, his definition is
$$\langle f,f\rangle={3/\pi\over [SL_2(Z):\Gamma_0(N)]}\int_\Phi |f|^2 dx dy.$$

Then in (2.5) you have
$$\langle f,f\rangle={\Gamma(2)\over (4\pi)^2}\cdot\mathop{\rm res}\limits_{s=2} D(s,f,f)$$
where by the last display of Section 1 he defines
$$D(s,f,f)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n^2\over n^s}.$$
Now a comparison of Euler products gives that the local factors
of $D(s,f,f)\zeta(2s-2)$ and $L(s,Sym^2 f)\zeta(s-1)$ match, at least away from $p$ that divide $N$ (this discrepancy is the issue that David Loeffler raises). This Euler product comparison is mentioned in another paper of Shimura, see (0.4) of https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-31.1.79

Anyway, this gives the answer up to the bad factors,
namely
$$\int_\Phi |f|^2 dx dy={[SL_2(Z):\Gamma_0(N)]\over 3/\pi}\langle f,f\rangle$$
$$=[SL_2(Z):\Gamma_0(N)]{\pi\over 3}{1\over (4\pi)^2}\mathop{\rm res}\limits_{s=2} D(s,f,f)$$
$$=[SL_2(Z):\Gamma_0(N)]{\pi\over 48\pi^2}{1\over\zeta(2)}L(2,Sym^2 f)\prod_{p|N} C_p$$
$$=N\prod_{p|N}(1+1/p)\cdot{1\over 8\pi^3}L(2,Sym^2 f)\prod_{p|N}C_p$$

Note that this matches your asserted formula when $N=1$ and $k=2$.

In the more general case, considering a bad prime $p|N$, the Euler factor from $\zeta(s-1)/\zeta(2s-2)$ evaluated at $s=2$ exactly cancels out factor of $(1+1/p)$ in the index formula. Meanwhile, the Euler factor of $L(s,Sym^2f)$ when $p$ exactly divides $N$ is $(1-1/p^s)^{-1}$, as is the Euler factor of $D(s,f,f)$ in this case (since $a_p^2=1$).

Finally, when $p^2|N$, the Euler factor of $D(s,f,f)$ is trivial since $a_p^2=0$, while that of $L(s,Sym^2f)$ can be known either by theory or trial-and-error computation. For the theoretical side, one can presuably work with the $p$-minimal twist of $f$ where this minimality allows twists with nontrivial Nebentypus - see 2.1 of Coates and Schmidt, particularly (2.12). https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.375-376.104

I think one aspect is that if $v_p(N)$ is odd then the Euler factor of $L(s,Sym^2f)$ is trivial; while if $v_p(N)$ is even and $f$ is itself $p$-minimal then the factor is $(1+p/p^s)^{-1}$; and otherwise the Euler factor comes from that of the $p$-minimal twist (though perhaps not completely transparently, again with this $(1+p/p^s)^{-1}$ possibly appearing).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That allowed me to do the computation. I get the same as pari/gp after normalization @HenriCohen. I will also study the answer by Peter Humphries to get the Euler factors without guessing.

Answer (score 8):

Let $f$ be a newform of weight $k$, level $q$, and nebentypus $\chi$, where $\chi$ is a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q_1 \mid q$, and let $f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_f(n) n^{\frac{k - 1}{2}} e(nz)$ be the Fourier expansion of $f$, where the Hecke eigenvalues $\lambda_f(n)$ are normalised such that $|\lambda_f(n)| \leq d(n)$. Let $d\mu(z) = \frac{dx \, dy}{y^2}$ and let $E(z,s) = \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\infty} \backslash \Gamma_0(q)} \Im(\gamma z)^s$ denote the real analytic Eisenstein series for $\Gamma_0(q)$. Then by unfolding,
$$\int_{\Gamma_0(q) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |y^{k/2} f(z)|^2 E(z,s) \, d\mu(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} |\lambda_f(n)|^2 n^{k - 1} \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{s + k - 1} e^{-4\pi ny} \, \frac{dy}{y}.$$
We make the change of variables $y \mapsto y/(4\pi n)$. Since $\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} y^s e^{-s} \, \frac{dy}{y}$, we arrive at the identity
$$\int_{\Gamma_0(q) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |y^{k/2} f(z)|^2 E(z,s) \, d\mu(z) = (4\pi)^{1 - s - k} \Gamma(s + k - 1) \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda_f(n)|^2}{n^s}.$$

We take the residue of both sides at $s = 1$. Since the residue of $E(z,s)$ at $s = 1$ is
$$\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(\Gamma_0(q) \backslash \mathbb{H})} = \frac{1}{[\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) : \Gamma_0(q)] \operatorname{vol}(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H})} = \frac{3}{\pi q \prod_{p \mid q} (1 + p^{-1})},$$
we deduce that
$$\int_{\Gamma_0(q) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |y^{k/2} f(z)|^2 \, d\mu(z) = \frac{\pi q \prod_{p \mid q} (1 + p^{-1}) \Gamma(k)}{3 (4\pi)^k} \operatorname*{Res}_{s = 1} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda_f(n)|^2}{n^s}.$$
Next, we use the fact that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda_f(n)|^2}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta^q(s) L^q(s,\operatorname{ad} f)}{\zeta^q(2s)} \prod_{p \mid q} \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda_f(p^r)|^2}{p^{rs}},$$
where I write $L^q(s,\pi)$ to denote the $L$-function with the Euler factors dividing $q$ omitted, and $L(s,\operatorname{ad} f)$ denotes the adjoint $L$-function; if the nebentypus of $f$ is trivial, this is the same as the symmetric square $L$-function $L(s,\operatorname{sym}^2 f)$.

Since $\operatorname*{Res}_{s = 1} \zeta^q(s) = \prod_{p \mid q} (1 - p^{-1})$, whereas $\zeta^q(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \prod_{p \mid q} (1 - p^{-2})$, we arrive at the identity
$$\int_{\Gamma_0(q) \backslash \mathbb{H}} |y^{k/2} f(z)|^2 \, d\mu(z) = \frac{2 q\Gamma(k)}{\pi (4\pi)^k} L^q(1,\operatorname{ad} f) \prod_{p \mid q} \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda_f(p^r)|^2}{p^r}.$$

To simplify this any further, we need to use the local theory of automorphic representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ at each prime $p \mid q$.

- If $p \parallel q$ but $p \nmid q_1$, then the local component $\pi_p$ at $p$ of the automorphic representation $\pi_f$ associated to $f$ is a twist-minimal special representation (i.e. a special representation associated to an unramified character of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$), in which case $|\lambda_f(p^r)| = p^{-r/2}$, so that $\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} |\lambda_f(p^r)|^2 p^{-r} = (1 - p^{-2})^{-1}$. In this case, we have that $L_p(1,\operatorname{ad} f) = (1 - p^{-2})^{-1}$ as well.
- If $p \mid q$ but $p \nmid \frac{q}{q_1}$, so that $p^k \parallel q$ and $p^k \parallel q_1$, then $\pi_p$ is a twist-minimal principal series representation (i.e. $\pi_p = \omega_1 \boxplus \omega_2$ with one of $\omega_1,\omega_2$ unramified), in which case $|\lambda_f(p^r)| = 1$, so that $\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} |\lambda_f(p^r)|^2 p^{-r} = (1 - p^{-1})^{-1}$. In this case, we have that $L_p(1,\operatorname{ad} f) = (1 - p^{-2})^{-1}$ as well.
- In all remaining cases (so that $\pi_p$ is supercuspidal or a non-twist-minimal principal series representation or a non-twist-minimal special representation), $\lambda_f(p^r) = 0$ for all $r \geq 1$, so that $\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} |\lambda_f(p^r)|^2 p^{-r} = 1$. However, we do not necessarily have that $L_p(1,\operatorname{ad} f) = 1$ as well, and in fact this only occurs when $\pi_p$ is supercuspidal and not twist-invariant by the unramified quadratic character of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$.

Here we can determine the local factors at $s = 1$ of $L(s,\operatorname{ad} f) = L(s,f \otimes \widetilde{f})/\zeta(s)$ via [work of Gelbart and Jacquet](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1355) (namely Corollary (1.3) and Proposition (1.4)).

Comment: Arguably, the final step isn't really "simplifying" the formula any further: it's complicating it, in some sense, because $\lambda_f(p^r) = (\lambda_f(p))^r$ is a rather elementary invariant of $f$ -- you just read it off from the $q$-expansion -- while computing the isomorphism class of $\pi_p$ and hence the Euler factor $L_p(1, ad\ f)$ is much more involved (as I can say from experience: https://www.jstor.org/stable/23267992). This is my point in the comments above: computing the primitive Sym^2 L-function is a difficult and interesting problem but it is *not needed* for Petersson norms.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I agree completely. On the flipside, as an analytic number theorist, one often wants *bounds* for these quantities in the large $q$ limit, and here we have good tools for understanding the size of the primitive $L$-function $L(1,\mathrm{ad} f)$ (via techniques involving the functional equation for this $L$-function) but not the imprimitive $L$-function. So we really do need to have some careful control of the size of the bad Euler factors. Thankfully this is all doable via the methods sketched above.